# How can I get a query for this report in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have this sql database

[image]

And I want to show my data such as following:

[image]

Note:

> Total sales = Sum(ProductsTbl.SalePrice *
>   OrderDetailsTbl.SoldQuantity)
>
> Discounts = Sum(ProductsTbl.SalePrice * OrderDetailsTbl.SoldQuantity)
>   * DiscountRatesTbl.DiscountRate/100
>
> Payed = SUM(isnull(CashMovementTbl.CashMovementValue,00.00)

So how can I do a query in SQL Server to show data like that.

Thanks for any help.

I tried this query but failed to got Discounts:

```
SELECT  c.CustName as 'Customer' ,

Total Sales= ( SELECT SUM(p.SalePrice * d.SoldQuantity) FROM OrderDetailsTbl d 
INNER JOIN  OrdersTbl o ON d.orderID = o.orderID INNER JOIN  ProductsTbl p ON p.ProductID = d.ProductID
WHERE o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID ) ,

Discounts= (Select isnull(sum(p.SalePrice * d.SoldQuantity)* dr.DiscountRate/100),00.00 FROM OrderDetailsTbl d 
INNER JOIN  OrdersTbl o ON d.orderID = o.orderID INNER JOIN  ProductsTbl p ON p.ProductID = 
d.ProductID inner join DiscountRatesTbl dr on dr.orderID = o.orderID WHERE o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID ) ,

Payed=  ( SELECT  SUM(isnull(cm.CashMovementValue,00.00)) FROM CashMovementTbl cm
INNER JOIN OrdersTbl o  ON o.orderID = cm.orderID WHERE  o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID)

FROM    CustomersTbl c
where ( SELECT SUM(p.SalePrice * d.SoldQuantity) FROM OrderDetailsTbl d 
INNER JOIN  OrdersTbl o ON d.orderID = o.orderID INNER JOIN  ProductsTbl p ON p.ProductID = 
d.ProductID WHERE o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID ) is not null 
order by c.CustName
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @SuperHornet Yes I treied & add what I have in my question, but it failed :(

Comment: Just stupid thing: there is a typo: dr..orderID shouldn't be dr.orderID

Comment: @RafalZiolkowski so wrong input When I wrote this , but it still failed

Comment: What do you mean by failed to get discounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an optimal way for query writing...

But replace the part of your query for discount calculation with the following:

```
Discounts= (Select isnull(SUM(p.SalePrice * d.SoldQuantity* dr.DiscountRate/100),00.00) FROM OrderDetailsTbl d 
INNER JOIN  OrdersTbl o ON d.orderID = o.orderID INNER JOIN  ProductsTbl p ON p.ProductID = 
d.ProductID inner join DiscountRatesTbl dr on dr.orderID = o.orderID WHERE o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID ) ,
```

This will works.

Simply the `SUM` must include all multipliers and not simple multiplication of *`p.SalePrice`* and *`d.SoldQuantity`*